# Deploying application with EF

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, app-config

I've got a problem with deploying application with EF4.2 as ORM and MySQL as DB. I've add MySQL.Data (v.6.7.4) and MySQL.Data.Entity (v.6.7.4.1) to the project. My app.config has a following structure:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="userSettings" type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <section name="Settings.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="SUDBContext" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model.ORM.SUDB.csdl|res://*/Model.ORM.SUDB.ssdl|res://*/Model.ORM.SUDB.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;{0}&quot;" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <userSettings>
    <Settings.Settings>
      <setting name="RequestTimeout" serializeAs="String">
        <value>3000</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="FindOrderByBarcodeUrl" serializeAs="String">
        <value>http://developmachine.babadu.ru/exchange/restservice/getorderinfobybarcode.php?barcode={0}</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="ChangeOrderStateUrl" serializeAs="String">
        <value>http://developmachine.babadu.ru/exchange/restservice/changeordershippingstatus.php?id={0}&amp;status={1}</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="ConnectionString" serializeAs="String">
        <value>server=localhost;user id=root;password=qwerty123;persist security info=True;database=sudb</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="DefaultPrinter" serializeAs="String">
        <value />
      </setting>
      <setting name="IsDirectPrint" serializeAs="String">
        <value>False</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="FindOrderByNumberUrl" serializeAs="String">
        <value>http://babadu.ru/exchange/restservice/getorderinfobyid.php?id={0}</value>
      </setting>
    </Settings.Settings>
  </userSettings>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0" />
  </startup>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Data" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="EntityFramework" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.0.0" newVersion="4.2.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="MySql.Data" publicKeyToken="c5687fc88969c44d" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.7.4.0" newVersion="6.7.4.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

When I try to start application and make a query from the DB on developer machine everything is fine. By when I try to start it on client' machine i've got the error: "The specified store provider cannot be found in the configuration, or is not valid.". 
What I've made wrong?

P.S. MySQL .NetConnector v6.7.4 and .NetFramework v.4 has alreaddy been installed on client' machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made it! Thanks for the article [MySQL Forum](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?38,590719,594455#msg-594455) I've found the cause of the bug. What I've done:

1. Register new provider **MySQL Data Provider**
2. Add tag **remove invariant**
3. Set providerName to **System.Data.EntityClient** in connection string tag
4. Set provider to **MySql.Data.MySqlClient** directly in connection string

Modified App.config has the following strucure:

```
<configuration>
  ...
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="SUDBContext" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model.ORM.SUDB.csdl|res://*/Model.ORM.SUDB.ssdl|res://*/Model.ORM.SUDB.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string='{0}'" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  ...
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
      <add name="MySQL Data Provider"
         invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"
         description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL"
         type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data"/>
      </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
```

...